# "WHERE ... IN ..." , "WHERE ... != ..." query indexing issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I am using **MySQl** database.

I know if I create a **index** for a column, it will be fast to query data from a table by using that column index. But, I still have the following questions:

(suppose I have a table named **cars**, there is a column named *country*, and I have created index for *country* column)

1. I know for example the query `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE country='japan'`will use the index on column *country* to query data which is fast. How about `!=` operation? will `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE country!='japan';` also use index to query data?
2. Does `WHERE ... IN ...` operation use index to query data? For example `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE country IN ('japan','usa','sweden');`

Comment: you can run explain and the your query and see if mysql use your index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXPLAIN SELECT` to find out if your query uses an index or not.

For example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE foo NOT IN (1,4,5,6);
```

Might yield:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ALL  | NULL          
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------

+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

In this case, the query had no `possible_keys` and therefore used no `key` to do the query. It's the `key` column you'd be interested in.

More information here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html

Answer (score 3):

The general answer is: it depends. It depends on what the database optimizer thinks is the best way to retrieve the data, and its decision may need on the distribution of the data.

For example, if 99% of your rows have country = 'japan', maybe the first query (`=`) will not use the index, but the country with `!=` will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ['EXPLAIN'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to see what happens with your query. You will probably be interested in the 'possible_keys' and 'key' column.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE `country` != 'japan'
```

Answer (score -1):

Both queries will use indexes (assuming there is index with `country` as it's first column)

When in doubt use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html). You will also want to read (at least parts of) [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: -1, Setting an index does **not** guarantee that (My) or any SQL will use an index.  What matters is the cardinality of the index and the % of rows that MySQL thinks will be hit by the query.

Comment: I guess you're right. Correct answer should be 'neither `!=` nor `IN()` makes MySQL NOT use indexes. Whether they will be used depends on some additional factors'